# nginx as reverse proxy with failover

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, failover

I am running a wordpress website in a such a way that my frontend is managed by Nginx. Nginx forwards All the dynamic content to varnish and varnish subsequently forwards to apache. Now i want to configure in a such a way that nginx forward the request directly to apache if varnish is stopped/failed. how can i do that.

Comment: I have come accross that explanation: https://gist.github.com/ZoidQC/20b234cec147a4413117b929302d95b7 - maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by load balancing method. **Nginx** load balancing uses the `upstream` module. The simplest way is to add upstream block inside http field in `nginx.conf` file located at `/etc/nginx/`.

```
http {

   upstream backend {

      server 127.0.0.1:8081; 
      server 127.0.0.1:8088;
    # server Backend_Server_IP;  
   } 
...

}
```

Here I have considered that **varnish** is running on `localhost` with `port 8081` while **apache** is running on `localhost` with `port 8088`. Specifying IP address and Port number for Varnish wasn't necessary here but I have added it just in case.

After this, you just need to edit inside site setting which is located at the directory `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`. Just open your site file and add these lines in it.

```
location / {
     # First attempt to serve request as file, then
     # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

     proxy_pass http://backend;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Now Save it, Close it and then check nginx configuration file for any syntax error by typing:

```
   sudo nginx -t
```

Restart the nginx service if syntax is ok.

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

It will work like a charm. You can check it by stopping varnish service and then visit your site. **nginx** will bypass **varnish** if varnish service got failed and then it will forward its request to **apache** :-)

Comment: this is not "failover" but load-balancing. If you want failover, you need to add the flag "backup" to one of the backends.